# calling a static method

Tags: java, static-methods

How come this piece of code shows compiling error-void is an invalid type for the variable test

```
public class Tester{
        public static void main(String[] args){
           static void test(String str){
         if (str == null | str.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("String is empty");
         } 
         else {
            System.out.println("String is not empty");
         }}
       test(null);
```

Comment: Move your `test` method out of the `main` method

Comment: DO NOT compare Strings with ==, rather with .equals(). Strings Re objects, and if you want to compare the value of objects you need .equals(), otherwise you are comparing references.

Comment: if one of the operands is null == works and you should use it because if your str is null, str.equals(null) will throw a NullPointerException
-1 to comment

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to declare one method (`test`) within another method (`main`). Don't do that. Move `test()` to be in the class directly:

```
public class Tester{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(null); 
  }

  static void test(String str) {
    if (str == null | str.length() == 0) {
      System.out.println("String is empty");
    } else {
      System.out.println("String is not empty");
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that I've also fixed up the indentation and whitespace. There are various conventions you can use, but you should be consistent and rather clearer than the code in your question showed.)

Comment: thank you ,clearing up the concept and about the code conventions

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare a method inside another method. Put off `test` from `main`. And you also can't call a method from the class. `test(null);` must be inside a method, say main.

```
public class Tester{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            test(null);
        }

        static void test(String str){
         if (str == null | str.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("String is empty");
         } 
         else {
            System.out.println("String is not empty");
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method test is inside another method.

Just put test method outside of your main.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tester{

    public static void test(String str){
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("String is empty");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("String is not empty");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        test(null);
    }

}
```

You also have to add the double or operand (||) in order to work properly without Null Pointer Exception Error.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring test method inside main method. So, separate the test method from main.

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void test(String str)
    {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("String is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("String is not empty");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test(null);
    }
}
```